# Why does the webpage cannot be displayed properly on iphone?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, frontend

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Jack Yuan | Web Developer</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/normalizemore.css">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gloria+Hallelujah' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,cyrillic-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/responsive.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

    </head>

    <body>

        <header>

            <a href="index.html" id="logo">
                <h1>Jack Yuan</h1>
                <h2>Web Developer</h2>
            </a>

            <nav>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html" class="selected">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="item.html"> Items For Sale </a> <li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="more.html"> More </a> </li>
                </ul>

            </nav>
        </header>
        <section>
            <ul id="gallery">
                <li id="pic1">
                    <a href="PortImg/001.JPG">
                    <img src="PortImg/001.JPG" width="500" height="400" alt="">
                    <p> Columbia/Erbsville </p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="pic2">
                    <a href="PortImg/002.JPG">
                    <img src="PortImg/002.JPG"width="500" height="400"  alt="">
                    <p> Columbia West </p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="pic4">
                    <a href="PortImg/004.JPG">
                    <img src="PortImg/004.JPG"width="500" height="400" alt="">
                    <p> Broadwalk </p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="pic5">
                    <a href="PortImg/005.JPG">
                    <img src="PortImg/005.JPG"width="500" height="400" alt="">
                    <p> Columbia Lake</p>
                    </a>
                </li>

                    <li id="pic6">
                    <a href="PortImg/003.jpg">
                    <img src="PortImg/003.jpg"width="500" height="400" alt="">
                    <p> Conservation Area </p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="pic7">
                    <a href="PortImg/007.JPG">
                    <img src="PortImg/007.JPG"width="500" height="400" alt="">
                    <p> Erb</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
        <footer>
            <div id="mus">
            <embed src="In Christ Alone.mp3" loop="true" autostart="true" height="55mm">
            <p> In Christ Alone </p> 
            <p>Presented by <a href =https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RzseOqwn8oo">Christina Grimmie</a></p>
            </div>
            <div id="logo">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/jackyuan.jack">
            <img src="img/facebook.gif" alt="FaceBook Logo" class="icon">
            </a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/Jack19909100">
            <img src="img/twitter.gif" alt="Twitter Logo" class="icon">
            </a>
            </div>
            <p>Jack Yuan</p>
            <p>All Rights Reserved.</p>
        </footer>

    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
a {
        text-decoration:none;
    }

#logo {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}

h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 4mm;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 0.8em;
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin: -5px 0 0;
    font-weight: normal;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;
}

a {
    color: #6ab47b;
}

header{
    background: #6ab47b;
    border-color:#599a68;
    float:left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    width: 100%;
}

nav{
    background:  #599a68;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px 0 0;
}

nav a, nav a:visited {
    color:#fff;
}

nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 0;
}



nav a{
    font-weight: 800;
    padding: 15px 10px;
}

h1, h2{
    color:#fff;
}

h3{
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}

nav a.selected , nav a:hover {
    color:#32673f;
}

footer{
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    clear:both;
    padding-top: 20px;
    color: #ccc;
    line-height: 0.8em;
    background: black;
    padding-bottom: 1mm;
}


img{
    max-width: 100%;
}

#gallery img{   
    width: 100%;
}

#gallery{
    margin:0;
    list-style: none; /** remove bullet point **/
}



#gallery li{
    float:left;
    margin: 2.5%;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    color: #bdc3c7;
}

#gallery li a p{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #bdc3c7;
}



.icon{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 5mm 5px;
}

body{
    background: orange;
    margin:0;
    color:#999;
}



/******
Page about
******/

.profile-photo{
    display:block;
    max-width:600px;
    margin:0 auto 30px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    padding-top: 10mm;
}



#confu{
    margin-top: 70mm;
}

#context{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; font-size: 1.5em;
}

#aboutsec{
    font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive; font-size:1.5em;
    text-align:center;
}



#mus p{
    margin-top:0;
    padding-top:0;
    line-height: 0.8em;
}

#item_gallery{
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
}

#item_gallery li{
    display:inline-block;
    padding-top: 22px;
    padding-right: 26px;
    padding-left: 26px;
    width:120px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#item_gallery p,img{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    color: red;
}


#sec{
    height:40cm;
}



@media screen and (min-width: 500px){     /** Consider as "if" statement **/
    #gallery li{
        width: 28.3333%;
    }

    #gallery li: nth-child(4n){
        clear:left;
    }

    nav li{
    display: inline-block;
    }

    #aboutp{
        float:right;
    }
    #aboutimg{
        width: 80%;
    }

@media screen and (min-width: 660px){
    nav{
        background: none;
        float: right;
        font-size: 1.75em;
        margin-right: 5%;
        text-align: right;
        width: 45%;
```

I used media query in my CSS file, and it works fine when I re-adjust the size of the browser window on my laptop. It does not work in my Iphone though? Just can't figure out why.

This is the the link to my code on fiddle: (including my html)
    http://jsfiddle.net/den330/pgH2b/

This is the address of my website so you may try it on your phone:
   jackyuan.org

Comment: What do you see? Can you show us?

Comment: Try adding the meta tag (in your html) for device width: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">`

Comment: @Hardy I had one there.

Comment: @Nathan Wride  a website without Navigation bar.  You may see the link i left at the end of my post.

Comment: What do you mean "displayed properly," "does not work," etc? These terms are way too vague.

Comment: @rvighne Navigation bar disappears when I browse on Iphone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran it through [csslint.net](http://csslint.net/) and found a few issues. The [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/builtbymay/pAj5N/).

Changed...

```
#gallery li: nth-child(4n){
```

to...

```
#gallery li:nth-child(4n){
```

Then made sure each of the breakpoints were closed properly.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 500px){     /** Consider as "if" statement **/
   #gallery li{
     width: 28.3333%;
   }

   #gallery li:nth-child(4n){
     clear:left;
   }

   nav li{
     display: inline-block;
   }

   #aboutp{
     float:right;
   }

   #aboutimg{
     width: 80%;
   }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 660px){
   nav{
     background: none;
     float: right;
     font-size: 1.75em;
     margin-right: 5%;
     text-align: right;
     width: 45%;
   }
}
```

That should do it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your jsfiddle and is working much nicer for mobile devices now.

Theres were a few problems:

- the media queries were missing a close bracket.
  `@media screen and (min-width: 660px){}`
- floating the listings mean the items werent stretching to the width of the device. Float:left was moved to the media query for larger screens
- the #gallery ul, was inheriting default browser padding - I set this to zero, but consider using a css reset in the future

  `#gallery{padding:0;}`

http://jsfiddle.net/pgH2b/2/

Cheers,
Dan